# In AstroJS get a single record from Strapi database

Tags: strapi, astrojs

In AstroJS (I'm new) I'm able to retrieve my full Strapi table data using these lines of code:

```
const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/teams?populate=*");
const { data } = await response.json();
```

Or using the Filters option to get a specific result eg

```
http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/teams?filters[name][$contains]=john;
const { data } = await response.json();
```

Both above is placed in JSON data.

I would like to use the finOne function that Strapi has in their documentation.

```
const entry = await strapi.db.query('api::blog.article').findOne({
  select: ['title', 'description'],
  where: { title: 'Hello World' },
  populate: { category: true },
});
```

1. My first question is what is api:::blog.artilce? I only have Strapi table names like Content and Teams.
2. My second question is why am I getting a error "strapi is not defined" when changing the api to my teams table?

```
const entry = await strapi.db.query('http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/teams').findOne({
  select: ['title', 'name'],
  where: { name: 'john' },
  populate: { category: true },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple of a simple implementation.

My collection type

[image]

Create a custom route.

```js
module.exports = {
  routes: [
    { // Path defined with an URL parameter
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/custom-query', 
      handler: 'item.customQuery',
    }
  ]
}
```

Create custom controller

```js
"use strict";

/**
 * item controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require("@strapi/strapi").factories;

module.exports = createCoreController("api::item.item", ({ strapi }) => ({
  async customQuery(ctx) {
    const entry = await strapi.db.query('api::item.item').findOne();
    return entry;
    
  },
}));
```

[image]

Then make the following request

```
{
  select: ['name', 'description', 'quantity'],
  where: { name: 'item 1' },
}
```

My response:

[image]

query: http://localhost:1337/api/custom-query?select[0]=name&select[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZGAE.png)=description&select[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Edh.png)=quantity&where[name]=item 1

You can use the query builder here https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/interactive-query-builder

Here is the repo project: https://github.com/paulnotfromstrapi/strpai-custom-controller-route/tree/main/src/api/item

Hope this helps, but you can accomplish the same thing just by calling the find method and passing appropriate filtering params.

No need to write custom code.

For the same example.

[image]

Instead of using the custom route I created, I am just going to use the find method that exists out of the box.

Now I am going to pass this query.

```
{
  filters: {
    name: "item 1",
  },
  fields: ['name', 'description', 'quantity'],
}
```

query: http://localhost:1337/api/items?filters[name]=item 1&fields[0]=name&fields[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZGAE.png)=description&fields[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Edh.png)=quantity

Here is my response.

[image]

Notice the additional benefits of returning pagination.  This is not something you get with `db.query` and will have to implement yourself.

So if you need to have ability to filter just use the `find` endpoint.

That would be my recommendation over the custom route with db.query that I showed.

Comment: I could have never worked that out by myself, massive thank you Paul. This video also helped me distile your answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyYgcl0K9XI

Comment: Glad I was able to help. And thanks for sharing the video.

Comment: I wanted to share here for any one interested.  I am working on Astro Strapi Starter, it is still work in progress.  But feel free to check it out.  https://github.com/PaulBratslavsky/strapi-astro-starter the stack is Astro, Strapi, Cloudinary and Neon DB.  The goal to deploy Strapi to Render and Astro to netlify.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you are wanting to be able to get an individual item from your `teams` collection.

You can accomplish this by passing the id of the item.

```js
const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/teams/1/?populate=*");
const { data } = await response.json();
```

I have created a 'team' collection type that has field 'name' and relation to 'users' in a field called 'teamMembers'

Team One has 2 users.

[image]

I made sure to give permission for 'find' and 'findOne'.

[image]

Team two has an id of `2` so when I run the following code:

[image]

When I run the following code: notice I am passing the id of the team.

```js
const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/teams/2/?populate=*");
const { data } = await response.json();
```

I get the following response.

```json
{
   "data":{
      "id":2,
      "attributes":{
         "name":"Team Two",
         "createdAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:53.198Z",
         "updatedAt":"2023-09-26T17:00:26.375Z",
         "publishedAt":"2023-09-26T17:00:26.375Z",
         "teamMembers":{
            "data":[
               {
                  "id":3,
                  "attributes":{
                     "username":"userthree",
                     "email":"userthree@email.com",
                     "provider":"local",
                     "confirmed":true,
                     "blocked":false,
                     "createdAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:32.483Z",
                     "updatedAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:32.483Z"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "meta":{
      
   }
}
```

If I run the code without passing the id, I will get the list of all the items.

```js
const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/teams/?populate=*");
const { data } = await response.json();
```

As you can see in this response:

```json
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Team One",
            "createdAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:43.442Z",
            "updatedAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:43.987Z",
            "publishedAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:43.984Z",
            "teamMembers":{
               "data":[
                  {
                     "id":1,
                     "attributes":{
                        "username":"userone",
                        "email":"userone@email.com",
                        "provider":"local",
                        "confirmed":true,
                        "blocked":false,
                        "createdAt":"2023-09-26T16:58:45.307Z",
                        "updatedAt":"2023-09-26T16:58:45.307Z"
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     "id":2,
                     "attributes":{
                        "username":"usertwo",
                        "email":"usertwo@email.com",
                        "provider":"local",
                        "confirmed":true,
                        "blocked":false,
                        "createdAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:12.655Z",
                        "updatedAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:12.655Z"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Team Two",
            "createdAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:53.198Z",
            "updatedAt":"2023-09-26T17:00:26.375Z",
            "publishedAt":"2023-09-26T17:00:26.375Z",
            "teamMembers":{
               "data":[
                  {
                     "id":3,
                     "attributes":{
                        "username":"userthree",
                        "email":"userthree@email.com",
                        "provider":"local",
                        "confirmed":true,
                        "blocked":false,
                        "createdAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:32.483Z",
                        "updatedAt":"2023-09-26T16:59:32.483Z"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "meta":{
      "pagination":{
         "page":1,
         "pageSize":25,
         "pageCount":1,
         "total":2
      }
   }
}
```

In terms of your questions.

1. My first question is what is api:::blog.artilce? I only have Strapi
   table names like Content and Teams.
2. My second question is why am I getting a error "strapi is not defined" when changing the api to my teams table?

This `api::blog.artilce` would refer to your content type id.  So if you have a content type teams the id would be `api::team:team`

But this is something that would be used in the your Strapi code and not in you Astro APP.

For instance.  This function is internal to Strpai and would not work in your Astro app.

It is used when you are looking to create custom controller or service within Strapi.

```
const entry = await strapi.db.query('api::blog.article').findOne({
  select: ['title', 'description'],
  where: { title: 'Hello World' },
  populate: { category: true },
});
```

The reasons why you are getting strapi is undefined, ( I am assuming ) you are trying to use the code inside your Astro app.

Is your project public, you can share the git repo I can take a closer look. I am not an expert on Astro but something I have been looking to learn.

In terms of Strapi, I used it daily.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I would like to however try use the Single Operations in the Strapi documentation https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/query-engine/single-operations. This is where I get the above code with that strange path api::team:team comes from. I've been told to change strapi.db.query to strapi.entityService but I think my issue is that I need to add a strapi end point to my Astro project, hence the strapi not defined error. I did try this strapi.entityService('http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/teams').findOne() but that did not work. Let me research the end point first.

Comment: So you are looking to create a new route, controller to call the findOne method that already exists?  I may be confused a bit. But yes, if you were to do it.  You would use entityService. 

1. you would create a route for the endpoint
2. you would create a controller for that route
3. in your controller you would use entityService ( but if you are using findOne ) it will still require id.  

Which basically you are recreating the functionality that already exists.  That I showed above.  When passing id in your query, Strapi is using single findOne operation under the hood.

Comment: We also have open office hours on Strapi's discord Mon - Fri 12:30 pm cst I hang out there a lot.  So if wanted to jump in and screen share what you are trying todo, I would be more then happy to help.  Lol. just wanted to extend the invite but I am cool chatting here too.

Comment: Strapi findOne() goes beyond the ID, you can use Select, Where, OrderBy etc a little like a SQL command. If I don't come right I'll try join a session.

Comment: Ok. I was not fully understanding what you were looking to achieve.  I finally understand.

You would need to create a custom route, controller, service and use 

Where you would be able to pass all the original queries that you were looking to do.

But you can also accomplish similar functionality by calling find and passing all appropriate populate and filters.